# How to return a page with 403 status code in nextjs14

Tags: next.js, error-handling, http-status-code-403

I am using Next14 (14.0.4) and developing a simple EditPost page. I would like to check if user is allowed to edit the post and show a proper error page.

```
const EditPost = async () => {
    const session = await getServerSession()

    if (!notAuthorised(session)) {
        throw new Error('Not allowed')
    }
    ....
```

I have a simple error.js page in my root folder:

```
const BlogError = ({ error }) => 
  <div>
    <h1>Error occured</h1>
    <p> { error.message } </p>
</div>)

export default BlogError
```

And unauthorised user is getting redirect to the page. The problem, is that the response has 500 status code, which is not desired. How to show the user error page with 403 status?

Comment: I found the solution, just in case someone found this.
Basically we need to add a route with this content:

`
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

async function GET(Request: Request) {
    return new NextResponse('Not authorised', { status: 403 })
}
export { GET }
`

And just redirect user to the page.